# Querying the route in the browser using Supabase

Tags: database, supabase

I have created a data table on Supabase.

[image]

I'm querying the route in my browser by appending the [anon key](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/quickstart#browser) as a query parameter:

https://<PROJECT_REF>.supabase.co/rest/v1/users?apikey=<ANON_KEY>

But I only receive an empty result `[]` in the browser.

I'm new to Supabase. Please help me!

Comment: Row Level Security (RLS) is enabled by default in Supabase. RLS prevents your data to leak to the public. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/row-level-security